# Determine what events or IO that Nodejs is waiting on?

Tags: node.js, debugging

Simple nodejs question.

I have a nodejs app that isn't exiting. I believe it's a connection to mysql that is keeping it open. Is there a way to print a list of whatever IO that nodejs is awaiting?

For example, if I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('world');
},50000);

console.log('hello');
```

Is there a way to find out that node is waiting for this timeout to occur?

EDIT TO ADD: I figured out it was a connection to a mysql db keeping the app open, but it was a fluke.

Comment: Have you tried to setting breakpoints and produce more output to see where and why it isn't exiting?

Comment: I have tried, but I'm not sure the debugger gives you anything more than a callstack.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: OS X. this is to add more chars...

Comment: (i haven't tried this) but maybe you could get all information you can get from the `node` process (and i don't mean the `process` object) and possibly find out what the process consumes (tcp connections/handles/ram/etc..). Although still debugging with breakpoints or producing more output should be considered the main step to debugging node.js scripts.